# Orderby() in tri-level entity structure

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have 3 entities that all encompass eachother. `MakeSource` can have many `ModelSource`s and `ModelSource`s can have many  `YearSource`s. The data I am retrieving looks like this:

[image]

So far I can only order by Makes and not models or years.

```
var data = context.MakeSources.OrderBy(P => P.Name).Include(A => A.ModelSources
                .Select(B => B.YearSources));
```

Placing more OrderBy calls within the include throws errors. My question is:

**How can I get a neatly ordered collection of first Makes ordered by asc, for each make its models ordered by ascending and for each model its years ordered by ascending?**

I tried using `ThenBy()` but then I cannot access nested properties of `ModelSource`

```
var data = context.MakeSources.Include(A => A.ModelSources
                .Select(B => B.YearSources)).OrderBy(P => P.Name).ThenBy(p => p.ModelSources.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I re-created your situation in my sandbox database, and wrote a linq query like this. This gives you a list of makes, models, and years. I used cars, but i really don't know what your data looks like.

```
var data = (from a in ctx.MakeSources
            join b in ctx.ModelSources on a.Id equals b.MakeSourceId
            join c in ctx.YearSources on b.Id equals c.ModelSourceId
            orderby a.Name, b.Name, c.Year
            select new { Make = a.Name, Model = b.Name, Year = c.Year }).ToArray();
```

This will give you a flat list

To order them in collections, such as each make has a collection of models, and models have a collection of years, I did this.

```
var data = (from a in ctx.MakeSources
        orderby a.Name
        select new
        {
            Make = a.Name,
            Models = (from b in ctx.ModelSources
                        where b.MakeSourceId == a.Id
                        orderby b.Name
                        select new
                        {
                            Model = b.Name,
                            Years = (from c in ctx.YearSources
                                    where c.ModelSourceId == b.Id
                                    orderby c.Year
                                    select new { ModelYear = c.Year })
                        })
        }).ToArray();
```

I am not aware of any easy way to do it using just includes and .OrderBy()s as it preloads the navigation properties, and the result in the include method has to be a collection of entities, as far as I am aware. So returning an ordered list won't load the entities (as evident by the error you received)